# Akairo Discord using fetch without import

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I'm using fetch to send data to a .json but since i can't refactor my requires to import and can't use fetch with require, i can't use it. And since it's not a web app, i can't use the script tag as i saw in other posts.

My code

```
*..*
fetch('./src/Data/hf.json', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
            title: args.args,
            createdByUser: user.tag,
            createdById: user.id,
            timestamp: message.createdTimestamp,
        }),
        headers : {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        if (res.ok) return res.json();
    });
*..*
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use fetch in this way. If you are looking to write JSON data to a file, you should probably be using the node fs module. https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp

Comment: I tried like that first but i end up with top level object problem on the .json. Maybe an alternative to it too ?